# Dealing with spam in edit suggestions

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, spam

A recent suggestion from an anonymous user on math.se: https://math.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/720 was obvious spam.

We could keep rejecting such suggestions, but I am afraid a lot of these could cause problems with the edit suggestion queue.

One option is to provide a flag as spam option, which will move it into the 10K flagged list and then we can ban the user, given enough spam flags.

Any (other) suggestions to deal with this potential problem?

PS: If I am missing some existing feature which already deals with this, please add that as an answer.

Comment: Why do you feel like this needs heavier artillery than the "Reject" button?

Comment: @Cody: Imagine 30-40 (or more) such edit requests.  Banning based on IP might serve as a preventative measure. Of course, this is just a potential problem and might be nothing to worry about and reject might well be good enough. If you notice, this is not tagged [feature-request], and it is not as if I feel we _need_ something different...

Comment: Sure, but you'd never get 30-40 such edit requests if you rejected the first few. As Jonathan mentioned, several rejected edits in a row bars the user from proposing any more edits.

Comment: @Cody: It does not have to be from one spammer, we could have multiple spammers and the edit suspension is only temporary, I believe, so they could come back...

Comment: So what are you suggesting that we do? The problem you couch in terms of edit suggestions could just as well present itself in posted answers. These get taken care of pretty well already. I'm just not sure I understand what you're asking for here... What problem are you trying to solve? Are you worried about clogging up the edit suggestion queue?

Comment: @Cody: Yes, I am thinking about the clogging of the suggestion queue. And I am _not_ suggesting anything (again! no [feature-request]).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No action is necessary. If enough suggested edits are rejected from an IP or user (both are tested) that IP or user cannot submit suggested edits for 7 days.

Comment: I wondered about that. That's a great solution.

Answer (score 3):

Reject is appropriate.  If the persion submitting the spam gets too many rejected edits, they get penalized somehow - I'm not sure of the details, but it is supposed to happen that way.

Comment: +1: I was under the mistaken impression that spam penalties are somehow different. I have accepted Jeff's answer, though.